# R - hdiffplot: change axis range

Tags: r, plot, axis

I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the x and y-axis value range for hdiffplot.
Here is my script:

```
xbnds <- range(x1,x2) 
ybnds <- range(y1,y2) 
bin1 <- hexbin(x1,y1,xbins= 200, xbnds=xbnds,ybnds=ybnds) 
bin2 <- hexbin(x2,y2,xbins= 200, xbnds=xbnds,ybnds=ybnds) 
erodebin1 <- erode.hexbin(smooth.hexbin(bin1)) 
erodebin2 <- erode.hexbin(smooth.hexbin(bin2)) 
hdiffplot(erodebin1, erodebin2)
```

I've tried: `hdiffplot(erodebin1,erodebin2,xbnds=range(-180,180),ybnds=range(-180,180))` but that doesn't change anything except for the color.

What am I missing?

Comment: What package is `hdiffplot` from?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - the library is hexbin